# Count checker from log file with bash script

Tags: bash

i have the script that has output logfile.txt :

```
File_name1
Replay requests : 5
Replay responsee : 5
Replay completed : 5
--------------------
File_name2
Replay requests : 3
Replay responsee : 3
Replay completed : 3
--------------------
```

I need to check that counts at all 3 line were the same, and if one of the line mismatched  move File_name to "echo".
I tried to grep with pattern file like cat logfile.txt | grep -f patternfile.ptrn with for loop, but there is no result, can`t find how to put first count in parameter that allow me to check it with next line, and how to check when there are many files_names at the logfile.
Pattern was :

```
Replay requests : 
Replay responsee : 
Replay completed : 
--------------------
```

Its a correct idea or mb i`m moving in wrong way?

Comment: I would extract the first count, save it into a variable, and then grep for all lines which do not have this count, and if there are any, move the file to wherever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to check that counts at all 3 line were the same, and if one of the line mismatched move File_name to "echo".

Here is one approach/solution.

Given your input example.

```
File_name1
Replay requests : 5
Replay responsee : 5
Replay completed : 5
--------------------
File_name2
Replay requests : 3
Replay responsee : 3
Replay completed : 3
--------------------
```

The script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while mapfile -tn4 array && ((${#array[*]})); do
  name="${array[0]}"
  contents=("${array[@]:1}")
  contents=("${contents[@]##* }")
  for n in "${contents[@]:1}"; do
    (( contents[0] != n )) && 
    printf '%s\n' "$name" &&
    break
  done
done < <(grep -Ev '^-+$' file.txt)
```

It will not print anything (filename) but change just one value of count (assuming count is the last string per line which is a number) then it should print the *filename*.

Note that `mapfile` aka `readarray` is a bash4+ feature.

The script above assumes that there are 4 lines in between the dashes that separates the *Filenames*.

> and how to check when there are many files_names at the logfile.

Not sure what that means. Clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a stating point for a script; I have not well understood the whole question and don't know what exact output is expected.

```sh
#! /bin/bash

declare -A dict

while read -a line ; do
    test "${line[0]}" == "Replay" || continue
    rep="${line[1]}"
    num="${line[3]}"
    if test "${dict[$rep]}" == "" ; then
        dict[$rep]=$num
    elif test "${dict[$rep]}" != "$num" ; then
        echo "Value changed for $rep : ${dict[$rep]} -> $num"
    fi
done < "logfile.txt"
```

If for instance the input is

```
File_name1
Replay requests : 5
Replay responsee : 3
Replay completed : 7
--------------------
File_name2
Replay requests : 2
Replay responsee : 3
Replay completed : 6
--------------------
```

the output will be :

```
Value changed for requests : 5 -> 2
Value changed for completed : 7 -> 6
```

Is it helpful?